# Grafana adds the timezone difference to dates

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone, grafana

I recently started using Grafana to show data I have in my PostgreSQL Database.
Now I've reached a point where when selecting data and using a certain timestamp field as the "time" field in Grafana, the data that's shown is the dates + timezone difference.

For example:
My data has the timestamp "2020-08-24 12:05:30" and my timezone is UTC+3, but Grafana shows it as "2020-08-24 15:05:30".

Is there any way to simply display the data as it exists in my DB without adding that timezone difference?

Comment: Is the field holding the data a ```timestamp``` or ```timestamp with time zone``` data type? Where is the data for the field coming from?

Comment: I tried both dateTime and timestamp without time zone, haven't tried timestamp.

Comment: There is no dateTime type in Postgres. ```timestamp``` is ```timestamp without time zone```. In any case you don't want to use that, you want ```timestamp with time zone```. I would spend some time here [PG Time and dates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the dashboard settings and make sure the timezone is set to UTC or whatever timezone is used by the data.

[image: Grafana dashboard settings]

Answer (score 1):

Changing the timezone wasn't my solution, as it would also shift "now".
I simply added an interval to my query:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(DateTime, 'YY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS') - interval '2 hour' as time
```

to shift it 2 hours

Answer (score 0):

The way I think it is intended to be used is:

Storing of dateTime values in the database should be in UTC only. (E.g. send a string representation of `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` to PostreSQL).

If you then select your timezone in Grafana's settings, things should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me to cast the type right in the request:
valid_for_dttm::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC'